# How to convert Ipl image to Mat image in java

Tags: java, opencv, iplimage

I am trying to make a mood detection app in `opencv`, `java`. But there is a lag in processing the image and then displaying the emoticon. So I want to directly use the image captured  , instead of copying the image to the hard disk. For that I need convert iplimage to matimage .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
IplImage *ipl_img;
Mat mat_img(ipl_img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     IplImage img;
     bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.width(), img.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

     bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(img.getByteBuffer());

     Mat mROI = new Mat(new Size(img.width(), img.height()), CV_8UC4);

     Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mROI);
```