# How to convert an IplImage to Mat?

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0, mat, iplimage

I am trying to understand how to make this conversion but I still have the same error. I need to convert IN JAVA an ipl image into mat to get the pyrDown of the image. 
Here the error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from opencv_core.IplImage to Mat

```
public class Image {
    IplImage i;
    public void downsample(){
        System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );             
        Mat Out= new Mat();
        Mat in(i); //  error in this line
        //Down sample the image by factor of 2
        Imgproc.pyrDown(in, Out);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not helping me at all. In this link they are talking about:
1) C++
2) an old constructor

Comment: Sorry for that, you miss the Java Tag. Also, it was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987989/how-to-convert-ipl-image-to-mat-image-in-java). `IplImage` is a deprecated format, and the constructor of `Mat` that had this class as input was removed in the newer versions of c++, and was never implemented in the Java version of OpenCV. I think JavaCV used it though. In the link there is some kind of solution, but it seems that it will be slow. Is it really necessary to use IplImage? or could you just use `Mat` from the start?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I need to convert this otherwise the only solution (for the main project) is to convert the frames of a video directly into mat or buffered image instead of IplImage, but I don't know if it's possible

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `i.getByteBuffer()` to obtain a byte array and then create a `Mat` of the same size and then use `put` to put the data in it

Comment: I did it man. I changed the system. I am getting frames with VideoCapture and processing them as mat objects. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day

Comment: @Api55, if you publish your comments as reply they can be upvoted, as the answer in the linked question seems to be outdated like you pointed. It could be helpful to futur visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Convert IplImage to Mat is simple.

> IplImage iplImage= cvLoadImage("image.png");
>
> Mat matImage = new Mat(iplImage);

vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Code that works for me:

```
    CvMat mat = cvLoadImageM (filename, iscolor);
```

If color: `iscolor=1`

If grey: `iscolor=0`

For example:

```
CvMat mat = cvLoadImageM("./image.png", 1);
```